# Admob ad listener (android)

Tags: android, events, load, admob

I want an event to happen in my app when an admob ad is loaded. I've been searching everywhere but I cant figure out exactly how to do this! Does anyone know where an example or tutorial is? I know it involves something with `public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad);`...

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) documentation, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
        // covers the screen.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
        // to the app after tapping on an ad.
    }
});
```