# AdView is blank on device but visible in Layout Inspector

Tags: android, admob, layout-inspector

I have an AdView inside of a ListView which, on some devices, its content is only visible the first time you scroll over it. If you scroll back up and down the view still takes up space, but its content is now blank - even though this is the same view. When I try to analyze this problem in the Layout Inspector, the view is visible again.

Are there any possible reasons for why the Layout Inspector shows something different from what is on the device screen?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a AdListener on your AdView in order to check whether ad is loading or not. Sometime there are not enough ads to serve.
[Admob ad listener (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556248/admob-ad-listener-android)

Comment: The ad loads and is displayed at first and I did not try to reload it.